# Oracle Query or statement issue, and performance tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having issues getting my query to execute properly. I have a table with 70 million rows. I'm trying to search the ip table for distinct ip's assigned to a customer between specific dates. These dates are controlled by a deallocation date.

Thus,

I'm trying to search the table for ips assigned to a customer when the deallocation date is null or between the 1st and 31st of a month. The query I have doesn't run very quickly, also the first time I ran it with or on the same line as deallocation_date is null, it returned every row.

Here is my query the first way I ran it, and it returned every customer not just the customer I was searching for, it took maybe 1 minute to start executing.

```
select distinct e.ip_address, 
a.customer_name,
c.vm_id, 
d.allocation_date, 
d.deallocation_date
from customers a, 
vm_groups b, 
vms c, 
vm_ip_address_histories d, 
ip_addresses e 
where a.customer_id=30
and a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
and d.ip_address_id = e.ip_address_id
and d.deallocation_date is null or trunc(d.deallocation_Date) between to_date('1-oct-14') and to_date('31-oct-14')
/
```

The second way I ran it, but it hasn't returned 15 minutes later

```
select distinct e.ip_address, 
a.customer_name,
c.vm_id, 
d.allocation_date, 
d.deallocation_date
from customers a, 
vm_groups b, 
vms c, 
vm_ip_address_histories d, 
ip_addresses e 
where a.customer_id=30
and a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
and d.ip_address_id = e.ip_address_id
and d.deallocation_date is null 
or trunc(d.deallocation_Date) between to_date('1-oct-14') and to_date('31-oct-14')
/
```

This way didn't solve it I thought it did, but it didnt return the values with deallocation dates.

```
select distinct e.ip_address, 
a.customer_name,
c.vm_id, 
d.allocation_date, 
d.deallocation_date
from customers a, 
vm_groups b, 
vms c, 
vm_ip_address_histories d, 
ip_addresses e 
where a.customer_id=30
and a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
and d.ip_address_id = e.ip_address_id
and (d.deallocation_date is null or trunc(d.deallocation_Date) between to_date('1-oct-14') and to_date('31-oct-14'))
/
```

I also tried and it returned only the values with null again.:

```
select distinct e.ip_address, 
a.customer_name,
c.vm_id, 
d.allocation_date, 
d.deallocation_date
from customers a, 
vm_groups b, 
vms c, 
vm_ip_address_histories d, 
ip_addresses e 
where a.customer_id=30
and a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
and d.ip_address_id = e.ip_address_id
and exists (select * from vm_ip_address_histories 
         where d.deallocation_date is null 
         or trunc(d.deallocation_Date) between to_date('1-oct-14') and last_day('1-oct-14'))
/
```

Comment: What are the query plans?  What indexes have been created?

Comment: I'm just trying to get it to return the correct information and I don't think my query conditions are right for what I'm trying to return.

Comment: if you check the correlated sub query I just posted it still only returned the values with deallocation date null. Also if you really need that info I will get it for you but I don't know it off the top of my head right now. I'm just trying to run down a ip assignment issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct e.ip_address, 
a.customer_name,
c.vm_id, 
d.allocation_date, 
d.deallocation_date
from customers a, 
vm_groups b, 
vms c, 
vm_ip_address_histories d, 
ip_addresses e 
where a.customer_id=30
and a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
and d.ip_address_id = e.ip_address_id
and (d.deallocation_date is null or d.deallocation_date between to_date('01-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date('31-10-2014 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
/
```